# How do I display a field twice in a node's display?

Tags: 7, entities

In my full node display I want to show the same field twice, in a different mode each time.

Specifically, I have a collection of images, I want one up top and the rest below in my already existing gallery view of the node. What I don't know how to do is to show the field for my image twice in a single node display. Is there a module that will allow me to do this with a minimum of fuss?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/node/1059636 and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42061/render-or-print-image-in-a-drupal-7-node-tpl

Answer (score 9):

Should be pretty easy if you use Display suite:

Add a dynamic field (admin/structure/ds/fields/manage_ctools) and select the entity type (node).

[image]

Your new field should be in the manage display tab of the entity type selected, activate it (put it in the section you want).

Click on the gear icon and then 'select content'

[image]

Then drill down in the options (node -> the field you would like to duplicate)

[image]

If you don't use display suite just print that field in a tpl.php file.

Comment: You lost me after selecting the `Node` checkbox.

Comment: I created the field and I think I correctly referenced the entity, but I can't find it to insert it in `admin/structure/types/manage/mynodetype/display`

Comment: I've added screenshots, sorry they are in french :)

Comment: The screenshots are a big help. And once upon a time, I could read French too. I can't seem to find the dynamic field in the `Manage Display` tab of the node editor.

Comment: Sorry mate, can't really help you more than this

Comment: You need to do the following to see the field in the display.

"Select A Layout" in the display for the content type and click save. Once you do that, the custom field you created will show up, as will the buttons that will allow you to create more custom fields directly from that page.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1162240#comment-7519979

Comment: Also make sure Display Suite Extras and Display Suite UI modules are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Display suite for the given view mode, you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/entdispfieldui instead. (in combination with a number of other modules)

- Choose a way to integrate 3rd party composer libraries: Either using composer_manager, or using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project
- Download and enable entdispfieldui and required modules, including cfrplugindiscovery (shipped with cfr).
- Scroll to the bottom of the view mode configuration page, create a new entdisp field, save.
- Move the newly created entdisp field up to the place where you want it.
- Configure the entdisp field as "Field with formatter", choose the field + formatter you like.
- Alternatively, choose "Image with processor" or "Images" (for multiple-value), then choose the image field as the source.

> I have a collection of images, I want one up top and the rest below in my already existing gallery view of the node.

This complicates the matter a bit. I am not sure if the usual formatter settings allow to specify which field items to display (e.g. only the first item, or all except the first). Something like this can be achieved with new custom renderkit components, but it depends a bit on your exact requirements.