# How to show one field in more than one regions?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, display-suite, theming

I'm using Drupal 7. I have used *two column stacked* layout to display Node Fields. I created one *Rating Field* and I showed it in top region. I want to show the same field in bottom region also. How can I show the same field in bottom region?

Comment: Please mention the Drupal version, to have more accurate answer to your questions.

Comment: Similar question has been answered earlier. Check [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/94399).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using ***Dynamic fields*** in **[Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)** Module. Check [this ans](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/94399).

Please find the detailed steps below to achieve this:

1. Navigate to **Manage Display** page of *Content Type* and click on "**Add a Dynamic Field**".
   [image: Click on Add Dynamic Field]
2. Add **Unique Label** (e.g. "*Duplicate Field*") to Field and Select valid **Entities (e.g. "*Node*")** based on your requirement.
3. Click on **Save**.
   [image: Create dynamic field]
4. This will create a Dynamic Field and Display on ***Managed Display*** page of ***Entities*** you've selected.
5. Re-position newly created field (*i.e. Duplicate Field*) into another region, say as **Footer** and click on **Settings** icon as shown in screenshot.
   [image: Re-position Field]
6. This will open a *display settings* for this field. Click on **Select Content**, to select the field you want to display the content of.
   [image: Open settings]
7. From left menu, select **Node** and then click on **Node field (*e.g. "Field: Body (body)"*)**.
   [image: Select valid node field]
8. On next screen, change settings based on your requirement for *displaying label, display formatter* and click on **Continue**.
   [image: Update field display settings.]
9. Click on **Finish**
   [image: Click on Finish]
10. Now you need to tell Display Suite that I've selected field and attached it to **Dynamic Field** by clicking on **Update** Button.
    [image: Click on update settings.]
11. This will show a preview of *Field Name*, you've attached to Dynamic field.
    [image: Field Name preview]
12. Click on **Save** of *Manage Display* Page.

Comment: i cant able to add dynamic field. need any module installation? i can't able to see add dynamic field page

Comment: Make sure you've **Display Suite UI** Module enabled.

Comment: Thanks its working. **Display Suite UI** module was not enabled so that i can't able to dynamic field creation page.