# How to print a field value in page front tpl file?

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm trying to load a field value (machine name: field_theme_image) from a content of node value 3, in "page--front.tpl.php".

```
<?php
  $node=node_load(3);
  print $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri'];
?>
```

Using the above code I'm not getting full URL value. Please see the image below. I can see the path value in Devel themer.

[image]

Comment: `$node=node_load(3);`

Comment: Yes, changes but still not working. Please help

Comment: well what are you trying to do?  from the field name I am assuming you want to put an image in there, and there's a lot more to do than just print some text if so .

Comment: Yes, you are right. you code works if I print field "body"

   print $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['value'];

It would be helpful, if I can get url value of uploaded image.

Comment: Hi, I load this "print $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri'];" 
And got this value "public://395169_107851549383359_2007132000_n.jpg" 
I wonder how to make this to downloadabe url

Comment: Check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42061/render-or-print-image-in-a-drupal-7-node-tpl?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, I think you want to show a download link for an image on your home, you have image on your node with node id 3.

In this case you can use [download_file](https://drupal.org/project/download_file) module, it allows to create direct download link for fils/images.All you need to do is create a view(through views module) of display type block, in your view add image field and keep the formatter as direct download file, place this block on front page.

If you want to render the download link programmatically, you can use the same function as defined in download_file module to render the links.

If you want to print image programmatically consider this:

```
print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'home_theme'));
```

Comment: I am trying to load the upload image of node 3 in page--front.tpl file. 
I am able to see the path using devel info. Please see the screenshot above

Comment: But I don't know how to get that path value

Comment: are you trying to show the download link of the image or you want to print the image?

Comment: I am trying to load an image created using an image style in page--front.tpl.php. Please refer this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98458/need-path-of-an-image-created-using-an-image-style

Comment: check with the updated answer

Comment: @ Arpity: And what if I want to theme the origional image?
just want to know in case, I need. Thanks again.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7

Comment: Arpitr, now I have a problem here withe code. It throws error message if any page doesn't have image uploaded. It works fine with pages having this images 
    print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'page_theme'));