# need path of an image created using an image style

Tags: theming, media

```
<?php
  $node=node_load(3);
  $theme_img = file_create_url($node->field_theme_image[$node->language][0]['uri']);  //origional image path
  print $theme_img;
?>
```

I am trying to load an image in "page--front.tpl.php", which was created from a content of node value 3. 
Using above code, I am able to get origional image url. But I need path of image created using image style (home_theme)

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42061/render-or-print-image-in-a-drupal-7-node-tpl?rq=1 should give you some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [image_style_url($style_name, $path)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7)

Example:

```
$img_url = $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri'];
<img src="<?php print image_style_url("thumbnail", $img_url); ?>" />
```

Where you will be replacing thumbnail with the image style name you have in place