# Alter an image field using an image style rule

Tags: 7, media

I have a Template file for a specific content type with several images, and to prevent the user from uploading more image sizes, I have an image style rule to crop out the image to 140x140 pixels.

My question is, what would the image style method call look like, to return the altered image back to the template, if provided the field reference from the node in either a `$node->field_image` or a `$content[field_image]` call in the template?

Comment: If you want to print an image field with an image style preset, see this answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/42062/1899 . If you want to crop the image when uploading, and discard the original image, you will need a module for that.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Can you think of a reason why the return result from theme would return a broken image?